# How to handle javascript formdata with multiple files on PHP server side?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I'm struggling how to handle **multiple images** sent to controller via ajax and put them into storage. I've read that I should make new **FormData object**, and I did that.

Let's look at my code:

HTML:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="formularz">
          <label class="btn btn-sm btn-success" for="files">
            <input id="files" type="file" name="zdjęcie[]" multiple style="display:none;" onchange="$('#upload-file-info').html($(this).val());">
            <i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i> Dodaj zdjęcia
            <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{Session::token()}}">
          </label>
          <label class="btn btn-sm btn-danger deleteImages">
            <i class="fa fa-times-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i> Wyczyść
          </label>
          <br>
          <div class="chosenImages">
            <output id="list"></output>
          </div>
</form>
```

JS:

```
var formData = new FormData($('#formularz')[0]);

      $.ajax({
        method:"POST",
        url:postAddNews,
        data: {
          formData:formData,
          _token:token
        },
        cache:false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success:function(data){
            console.log("success");
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(data){
            console.log("error");
            console.log(data);
        }
     });
```

On the server side I would do it like that (without sending via ajax):

```
$files = $request->file('zdjęcie');

$i = 1;
$filename = array();

foreach($files as $file) {
        Storage::disk('local')->put('newsimages/'.$i.'.'.$file->extension(), file_get_contents($file));
        $i++;
}
```

When I inspect the formData object I can only see this:

[image: Inspecting element]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you have to change:

```
var formData = new FormData($('#formularz')[0]);
```

by the above code you are adding only one file to formdata, but `multiple` attribute is also there. So you have to append all of the files in formdata like:

```
var frmData = new FormData();
$.each($('#formularz_images')[0].files, function(i, file) {
    frmData.append('formularz[]', file);
});
```

and you can get them in controller like:

```
$data  = Input::all();
```

here $data contains `formularz` index in it, which contains all the images in it. Use `foreach()` to get individual images like:

```
foreach($data['formularz'] as $image)
{

}
```

Comment: I've tried your solution, it seems nice, but the problem occurs when I try to access `$('#formularz')[0].files`.

Comment: Ok. I've found way to solve the problem. Thank you for your solution.

Comment: I hope this help you